# How to scale texture properly?

Tags: uv

[image]

SO basically my texture is showing off way to big and when i tried to fit all my unwrapped parts in the 2D editor, i had to scale them very small which caused this problem.

I have red somewhere else that i had to do: Add>Vector>Mapping and change the scale. I tried to connect the cables as the pictures showed (I have plugged it into UV now, not object as the pic shows btw) , but im sure i am missing some plugs here.

What else needs to be done?

Appreciated if it could be explained in clear steps, im only a beginner.

EDIT: here to show the multiple UV maps.. at least i think they are :)

[image]

Comment: well if you have as you mentioned already plugged the UV output socket into the normal input of the mapping node, it should work already. Just a matter of finding the right scale values. One showstopper might be the objects themselves, if the scale was not applied before unwrapping you might get distorsion.

Comment: I changed the scale in 8, 10, 8000, 0.5, 00.5 but nothing changes. 
You mean scaling the objects in object mode with ctrl+A? I did that otherwise the UV editor wouldnt show them as the correct unwrapped model. I really dont get what is stopping me here. The pillows looks fine though since i didnt scale them so much as the other parts to fit in.

Comment: Do you have more than one UV Map on this object? Or more than one Material? That would make sense: You'd be changing and tuning a material which isn't assigned to any face.

Comment: How do i check both? I think i do have multiple UV maps, but dont know how to delete them. About materials i have no idea. ( I have edited my first post with a picture of the multiple Uv maps.. i think.. i only need the first one named 'beige').

Comment: well that's materials, not UV maps. I've tried an answer below, maybe that points you the right way

Comment: i did the below. I now only have one uv map and one material (they were already gone somehow, not sure what i did but ok). 
But the last step you are showing isnt possible. I dont have a uv map in the input tab.. ?

Comment: Had blender 2.7 so figured out it didnt have the uv map, but now i have 2.78 and it doesnt work both ways. With the uv map or with the coordinate texture UV... I really dont get it anymore. Spend more hours on this than the actual couch..

Comment: Is it possible to upload this blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? It would make tracking down the issue a whole lot easier.

Comment: wait a minute: are you only previewing the textures using texture view? or are you also testing the textures when rendering? I'm asking because texture preview (you have it enabled in your screenshot) does not take the mapping node into account. Switch to material preview instead!

Comment: I've edited my answer, at the end there is an explanation of what I mean in detail.

Comment: Yup that was it. But if i change the scale with every tiny bit, it never looks right. It seems the whole pattern is just moving on my object and all the different parts are out of place. I assume this only works if you do it with one texture that goes on the whole couch and not if its done in parts. Or do i need to select something separately? Sorry for al the questions dude, im trying to finish at least one thing :p

Comment: no worries. The tricky thing about unwrapping is to place the seams on the model in a way so the areas which you see in a render or on screen are always linked together. Cut the UVs in areas where one cannot see it if possible, or cut them where the real model would be cut (like, on a couch, there will be real sewing seams anyways. Cut there) One more thing: In the UV editor you can run a command called 'average islands'. That will try to resize the individual islands so they match the model better in terms of proportion. The different parts shall have more uniform scale then. Shortcut: Ctrl+A

Comment: I was hoping for a way to just scale the texture within its shape. Guess thats not possible right? Then it might be better to fit the unwrappings in two sheets? so their scale could be bigger. Not sure how that would be done though.

Comment: as long as the texture itself is repeatable, you can scale the UVs bigger than the usual 0-1 range no problem. If the texture is not repeatable, you'll see a seam.

Comment: I tried many ways. Keep bumping in the problem that the legs of the couch should have a different texture. That one keeps overlapping whenever i scale the couch. I dont see a way where this wouldnt happen, but where i can scale the texture of the couch as well. I am thinking to just use 2 UV maps so the parts can be bigger. Dont know if thats possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have multiple sources, two of them I could think of at the moment is that you have:

- more than one material in the Material Slots, and you're editing one that is not assigned
- more than one UV Map on the object, and the one which is currently renderable is empty

To check the material assignment, you can use the Material Tab like this:

[image: multi Material]

To check the UV Maps, you can use the Mesh Data Tab, UV Maps section:

[image: multi UV]

Regarding the UV map, the one with the camera icon behind is the one that is sent down the material tree when you plug the UV output socket somewhere. To choose a different UV Map you can use the dedicated UV Map node:

[image: UV chooser]

## EDIT: One more option

This happens frequently: There is a difference between Texture Preview and Material Preview. Material Preview tries to replicate the look of the final material as close as possible, so it tries to evaluate the whole node tree. Texture Preview on the other end was designed more for texturing game assets, where mapping nodes would not be so important (I guess). Texture Preview shows you what the **selected** texture node in the node tree would look like if the image was mapped onto the UV space without any mapping happening. See this little explanation here:

[image: Material Preview]

Answer (score 2):

On a side note it is advisable, to load your image into the uv editor to see how the geometry matches the image.

The node setup is correct. Changing the scale values of the Mapping node will change the scale of the texture. This will work with object and with uv coordinates.

[image: change texture scale mapping node]