# How do you scale textures in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

In blender 2.8 I made a model of a door. I put a texture on the door mesh but it does not fit correctly. It needs scaling down. How do I scale it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale texture properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64632/how-to-scale-texture-properly) Same goes for 2.80.